# Object doesn't support property or method 'find' in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the references below in my form

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am trying find the contents of the title element from the below string.

```
var mytext = "<head><title>bad error</title></head>";
var err = mytext.find('title');
```

I am getting `Object doesn't support property or method 'find'` error.

My requirement is I want to get text between an element `<title>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) tag

`$(mytext).filter('title').text();`
 will give you title tag text.

Answer (score 3):

`find` is jquery method, not `string` method. Wrap your HTML string in jquery.

Use `text` to get the innerText of an element.

```
$(mytext).find('title').text();
```

Example:

```
var mytext = "<head><title>bad error</title></head>";
var err = $(mytext).find('title').text();

alert(err);
```

Comment: am getting empty  "" value using $(mytext).find('title').text();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mytext` is a string. Strings don't have find method. You want to create jQuery instance and use it. If your string indeed looks like you posted then result of jQuery parsing will already be a title element and all you need to do is to read it's text:

```js
var mytext = $("<head><title>bad error</title></head>");
var err = mytext.text();

alert(err);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi dfsq, Your solution is fine. in my string i have so many tag elements so i am getting text between all elements using text() method. i want to get only text between title element only.

Comment: Sure then in this case you of course need to use `find`, just remember to wrap your string into `$(mytext)` first: `$(mytext).find('title').text()`.